# Sonata Admin: One-to-many route to show action instead of edit

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

My problem is simple, but I can't find an answer anywhere in the docs or the code...

When configuring show fields for a one-to-many relation, the records correctly appear in a list on the show page. They incorrectly link to the records edit action instead of the show action. Is there an easy way to change this. Intuitively, I would guess it would look something like this:

```
$showMapper
  ->add('items', null, [
    'action' => 'show',
  ])
;
```

This obviously didn't work.

Also if anyone can point me to documentation where it lists what key value pairs are possible for `$fieldDescroptionOptions` that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is documentation for that part but to change the route the option should be something like this:

```
->add('items', null, ['route' => ['name' => 'show']])
```

Looked it up in the template:

`admin-bundle\src\Resources\views\CRUD\Association\list_one_to_many.html.twig`

Comment: I see. Its in the `generateObjectUrl` method. Thank you very much for you help. I'm afraid I would not have been able to follow this so well.